# Select text in a TextBoxWithHeight

Tags: c#, winforms, selection

Did anybody succeed in selecting text programmatically in a TextBoxWithHeight ?

I searched "selection in TextBoxWithHeight" on Qwant, on Bing and on Google, and read the titles of the first dozen of results on each, but there was not much echo about TextBoxWithHeight in them.

On StackOverflow there were two results, but the topic was to set the height of the control.

When I validated my question, the list of threads proposed included two ones about RichTextBox.
This is what gave me the idea to do a test with a RichTextBox, but it seemed I had no more success than with TextBoxWithHeight.

I tried this code :

```
txbText = new TextBoxWithHeight();
txbText.Text = "This is just a sample text";
txbText.SelectionStart = 8;
txbText.SelectionLength = 4;
```

and I intended to get the word "just" highlighted.

This works pretty good on a classical TextBox, but does not seem to on a TextBoxWithHeight, nor on a RichTextBox.

To help classify the question, I propose the tag "TextBoxWithHeight".

For sure you remember the constructor of TextBoxWithHeight:

```
public class TextBoxWithHeight : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
{

    public TextBoxWithHeight()
    {
        base.AutoSize = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What library is that class from?  It looks like a user generated type to me.

Comment: I suggest you set the RichTextBox `HideSelection` property to `false`. I don't know whether the custom Control you have mentioned is derived from TextBoxBase; if it is, it probably has it, too

Comment: I found TextBoxWithHeight in a forum, I should not be able any more to say which one. It is very handy in some situations, specially with some font sizes.

Comment: Without you telling us what it is we're not going to be able to help. It's not a standard control.

Comment: Jimi had the answer, in half an hour.

Comment: I told what TextBoxWithHeight is at the end of my question ; you can also find it there : [link](https://9to5answer.com/how-to-set-height-of-a-textbox)https://9to5answer.com/how-to-set-height-of-a-textbox

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jimi's quick comment, the problem is solved.

TextBoxWithHeight and RichTextBox have a HideSelection property, that you have to set to false in order to be able to visualise a selection.

Comment: and if you want the selection on the screen, it can be useful to add txbText.ScrollToCaret();